# Vintage Cast Iron Kitchen Sink

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

These brackets were used to hold up a large 1910 double drainboard cast iron sink. Has anyone ever seen how these are used?

[image: 2 large brackets]

[image]

Comment: That type of mount is still being used today, mostly for pedestal sinks.

Answer (score 4):

They mount on the wall (solidly into framing) and hooks on the back of the sink catch the pocket at the top of the bracket, typically. Gravity (which there is plenty of with a cast iron sink) does the rest.

It should be more obvious looking at the back the matching sink.

Comment: I would think that 3 screws (through the top 2 holes and the bottom hole) for mounting directly to a stud, or 4 screws (through the 4 holes on the "bump out") for mounting to a horizontal cleat. The cleat would be used if the sink doesn't line up directly with stud locations and should be attached securely to at least 3 studs. Also, an extra +1 for "Gravity (which there is plenty of with a cast iron sink)"!